# Why does my waist hurt during pullups?

Tags: stretching, pull-ups

I have started doing pullups again(after a year or 2), past 2 years I had been doing other sports such as dancing, running, pushups so I am kindof in shape.

But my [waist](http://anatomypic.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/the-human-body-organs-male-4.jpg)(as can be seen from the picute: external oblique) hurt when I do pullups, expecially when before I come down and straighten my arms. 
It also hurts when I stretch that part, the rest of the time I am totally find, I dont feel a thing.

What should I do? Should I take a break from pullups? Should I go see a doctor?

Comment: Can you define where, specifically, it hurts? Is it only at the top or bottom, or does it hurt afterwards as well?

Comment: Hurt, as in soreness or as in pain? Former options is good while the latter option requires a **diagnosis** or **form check.**

Comment: @EricKaufman added image link above, and Kneel it is more like a strain pain not soreness. It is probably related to stretching the muscle or something

Comment: My guess is your technique when doing a pull up is not quite right. Are you starting the movement using your lats without swinging your legs?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called a **hollow position**: http://maxwellsc.com/maxwellsc2/images/pro-cert-04.jpg

This should be your position while doing pullups. Bracing your abs and contracting your glutes would probably end your pain.

Comment: How about this position: http://suavv.com/wp-content/uploads/unassisted-pullup.jpg

Comment: Bracing abs can also be enough for elimination of pain; and you can still brace your abs in this position. But you will see more power when you contract both of them.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a pull up, it is important to tighten your abs and glutes while keeping any swinging motion to a minimum.  Perform pull ups slowly and methodically.  You don't want to jerk around as this can cause discomfort and unnecessary strain on other parts of the body.  Focus on your technique and repeat a low number of pull ups at a time.  Don't strive for 30 on your first shot - start out with 3 and add 3 more each week.  This will give your body time to adjust and will help you to perform pull-ups with control.